# how can I send a param to maintain some checkboxes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, materialize

### There were some similar topics and I tried them but I couldn't resolve.

### code

```
<td><%= check_box_tag "words_info[]",word.id,false,{id:id} %><label for="<%=id%>" >追加</label></td>
```

The above code is called by  below one which is a search form.

```
    <h2>フラッシュカードを作成してください</h2><br>
       <div class="col-md-12">
       <h4>検索</h4>
      <%= search_form_for @q,url:start_words_path do |f| %>
           <%= f.label :title_cont, 'タイトル' %>
              <%= f.text_field :title_cont %>
             <%= f.label :user_name_cont,"作者"%>
                <%= f.text_field :user_name_cont%>
          <%= f.label :answer_cont,"答え"%>
           <%= f.text_field :answer_cont%>
           <%= f.label :question_cont,"問題"%>
         <%= f.text_field :question_cont%>
          <%= button_tag :type => "submit", :class =>"btn btn-send" do %>
            <i class="material-icons left">search</i>検索
          <% end %>
       <%end%>
        <%= form_tag({:action=>"practice"}, {:method=>"get"}) do %>
          <%=render "words/words_index"%> #rendered here
         <hr>
        <%= submit_tag "完了" , class:"btn btn-large btn-send"%>
     <% end%>
  </div>
```

### Everything that I tried

```
<td><%= check_box_tag "words_info[]",word.id,params[:words_info]==word.id,{id:id} %><label for="<%=id%>" >追加</label></td>

<td><%= check_box_tag "words_info[]",word.id,params[:words_info].include?(word.id),{id:id} %><label for="<%=id%>" >追加</label></td>

 <td><%= check_box_tag "words_info[]",word.id,params[:words_info].to_s==word.id.to_s,{id:id} %><label for="<%=id%>" >追加</label></td>
```

### environment

ruby 2.3
rails 4.2.7
materialize css

Comment: Did you check if you `params` content after the search?

Comment: There was Nothing,nil but I can check the contents after the submit.

Comment: Try checking your params, I once have a similar problem and I was because I wasn't sending the correct value to params.

Comment: A quick way to check your params in you view is with `debug(params)`.

Comment: There was nothing so you mean that I gotta send the value to params in search form?

Comment: I think so (at least try that to see if it fix the problem).

Comment: but I couldn't ,The code was   <%= search_form_for @q,url:start_words_path(params[:words_info]) do |f| %>

Comment: Try this, **1)** leave you `search_form_for` as is in the question, **2)** add `@words_info = params[:words_info]` to your controller, and **3)** try in your 3 `check_box_tag` attempts replacing `params[:words_info]` with `@words_info`.

Comment: Ok,I will try as you said

Comment: I couldn't do that that I want